# Variable does not exist in in method

Tags: apex, map, schedulebatch, method, variable

I am trying to pass value from a map into a string set but get the error:
variable does not exist: NewToolsMap in my execute method. I tried to make my map public but this does not seem to work. How can i solve this?

```
global class NewToolsTaskHandler extends psb_tsr.ScheduledTaskHandler{

    private static final Integer BATCH_SIZE;
    {   //load config
        BATCH_SIZE = FixConfigRepository.cfg_Fix.Batch_Size_SO_Task_Handler__c.intValue();
    }

    global NewToolsTaskHandler(){
        setBatchSize(BATCH_SIZE);
    }
    MAP<Id, Stock_Product__c> NewToolsMap = new Map<Id, Stock_Product__c>();
    global override Iterable<psb_tsr.ITaskAction> DoInitialize(psb_tsr.IInitializeCommand initCommand){
        MAP<Id, Stock_Product__c> NewToolsMap = new Map<Id, Stock_Product__c>( [  SELECT  Id, Article_Code__c
                                                                                        FROM    Stock_Product__c 
                                                                                        ]); 
        system.debug('NewToolsTaskHandler|NewToolsMap: ' + NewToolsMap);
        Set<Id> spIds = new Set<id>();
        List<NewToolsTaskAction> actions = new List<NewToolsTaskAction>();

        for(id NewToolsId : NewToolsMap.keySet()){
            if(spIds.size() == 10){
                actions.add(new NewToolsTaskAction(spIds));
                spIds = new Set<Id>();
            }
            spIds.add(NewToolsId);
        }

        if(!spIds.isEmpty()) {
            actions.add(new NewToolsTaskAction(spIds));
        }
        return (List<psb_tsr.ITaskAction>) actions;
    }
    global class NewToolsTaskAction implements psb_tsr.ITaskAction{
        private Set<Id> spIdsToProcess;

        public NewToolsTaskAction(Set<Id> spIds){
            spIdsToProcess = spIds;
        }

        public void Execute(){
            Utils.log('spIdsToProcess: ' + spIdsToProcess);
            Set<string> spArtcodeSet = new Set<string>(); 
            for(integer x=0; x<spIdsToProcess.size();x++){
              spArtcodeSet.add(NewToolsMap.get(spIdsToProcess[0]).Article_Code__c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple problems here.

First, you've declared `NewToolsMap` as an instance variable of `NewToolsTaskHandler`, but you've then shadowed it with a local declaration inside the `DoInitialize()` method, so your instance variable will never be initialized beyond the empty `Map` it starts with.

Second, the inner class `NewToolsTaskAction` does not have access to its enclosing class's instance variables, so it cannot see `NewToolsMap` in either place it is declared. If you want that class to have access to this data, you need to pass it as a parameter to the `NewToolsTaskAction` constructor, and store it as an instance variable in that class.